# OKHttp cache with expiration

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I am new to OkHttpClient and i don't know how to store cache for only 1 week.
So when agent update data, it will update in mobile too after 1 week.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MaxAge` and `MaxStale` parameter of `CacheControl`

#### `MaxAge`

Sets the maximum age of a cached response. If the cache response's age exceeds `MaxAge` it will not be used and a network request will be made

#### `MaxStale`

Accept cached responses that have exceeded their freshness lifetime by up to `MaxStale`. If unspecified, stale cache responses will not be used

```
public Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor(final int maxDays) {      
    return new Interceptor() {       
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(maxDays, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();
    
            return response.newBuilder()
                .header(Constants.CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
        }
    };
}
```

And later you can add this to your `HttpClient`

```
int MaxCacheDays = 7; 
httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor(MaxCacheDays));
```

Comment: Thank you for that great answer

Comment: If that answers your question then you can accept it. Thank you