# Caching image for a week

Tags: android, picasso

I am developing an Android application which is displaying lots of images. I am using Picasso for loading the image and using its default caching strategy. Now what I want is to modify the caching and suppose if user has seen an image today it will be there in the cache for next seven days and each time user visit that particular page Picasso load the image from cache, after 7 days the image will be cleared from cache and do a fresh caching again. Someone, please help me I am lost.

```
private void PicassoConfig() {
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader  (this, Constants.MAX_DISK_CACHE_SIZE));
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
}
```

then

```
Picasso.get().load(cardList.get(i).
   getImage()).noFade().priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).
   placeholder(R.drawable.placehoder_image).
   transform(new com.squareup.picasso.Transformation()
```

I want the image to be in the cache for a week.

Comment: Caching for image for seven days seem to impossible. But if you used Glide and use caching strategy it will more effectively. As, I have seen less caching with Picasso @B jha

Comment: @Venky `Caching for image for seven days seem to impossible` what does "impossible" mean to you?

Comment: Impossible in the sense if user didn't connect to network for seven days. But if he continuously connect to network then you need to verify caching each time when app make network call for image. But this might lead to some image display issue.@Zun

Comment: @Venky Are you sure about this? I've already done my research and know you're wrong. You can simply attach an interceptor and write your own caching mechanics which will cache an image without `some image display issue` (simply quoting your words)!

Comment: @Zun, I faced the issue if you have an solution it's great. Let me know I will make changes as per need.

Comment: Simple. Attach an okhttp interceptor and write a caching mechanic yourself. There are samples online and even classes you can subclass for additional behavior. The only thing you have to keep in mind is the user available storage since you don't want your app to use up gigabytes of data. Additionally, an image might be outdated so you should respect the cache headers as well. Now that I think about it, why would you want to cache an image for specifically 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom [OkHttp interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869978/4377954) and add to Picasso.

```
public Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor(final int maxDays) {      
    return new Interceptor() {       
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(maxDays, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();

            return response.newBuilder()
                .header(Constants.CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
        }
    };
}
```

Now, Add this to Gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
```

Now attach Custom `OkHttpClient` to `Picasso`. More info [**here**](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-2-5-integrate-okhttp3-as-network-stack)

```
okhttp3.OkHttpClient okHttp3Client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient();
int MaxCacheDays = 7; 
okHttp3Client.addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor(MaxCacheDays));  
OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttp3Client);  
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)  
        .downloader(new CustomOkHttp3Downloader(client))
        .build();
```